# Custom tag not working in XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which i need to covert using an XSLT.
The XML has custom tag  which is not getting resolved and I am not getting the result.

Following is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<di:itg_dataImport xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0"
                   xmlns = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:common = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0 data_import.xsd">
  <request>
    <requestType>Project Issue</requestType>
    <identifier>3</identifier>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Admin User (DEV)</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.DESCRIPTION</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Test - Pls Ignore</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.KNTA_ESCALATION_LEVEL</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Project</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.KNTA_MASTER_PROJ_REF</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>P0912002 IPTV Residential Phase 1</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.PRIORITY_CODE</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Normal</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.WORKFLOW_ID</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Issue Management Process</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
  </request>

</di:itg_dataImport>
```

Following is the XSLT being called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0"
                   xmlns = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:common = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0 data_import.xsd" >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<requests>
   <request>
    <requestType> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="di:itg_dataImport/request/requestType"/>
    </requestType>

   </request>
</requests> 

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the desired output is:

Project Issue

Can anyone please help in resolving and pointing where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**The XSL file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0"
    xmlns = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types"
    xmlns:common = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0 data_import.xsd" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <requests>
            <request>
                <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[local-name() = 'requestType']">
                    <requestType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </requestType>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </request>
        </requests>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result-Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<requests xmlns="http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types" xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0" xmlns:common="http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <request>
      <requestType>Project Issue</requestType>
   </request>
</requests>
```

Comment: While this works, I personally prefer to tell people what's wrong with their code, rather than just giving them an alternative solution that works. That way, they are less likely to come back for more help when they make the same mistake again on a slightly different problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's the number one XSLT coding error: your elements are in a (default) namespace, and you didn't specify the namespace when selecting them.

Comment: +1, I am very newbie in this field, and are gathering knowledge reading your book. Thank you very much, Sir, for showing the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

**To make what Michael Kay correctly points even more explicit, here is how to work with documents in a default namespace -- in your particular case**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0"
                   xmlns:x = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:common = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0 data_import.xsd" >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<requests>
   <request>
    <requestType>
    <xsl:copy-of select="di:itg_dataImport/x:request/x:requestType"/>
    </requestType>

   </request>
</requests>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I have made only a few short changes to your original code**:

1. The XSLT stylesheet no longer has a default namespace -- instead it has the same namespace specified with a prefix.
2. The `select` attribute of `xsl:copy-of` now has all the names prefixed.

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<di:itg_dataImport xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0"
                   xmlns = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:common = "http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types"
                   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0 data_import.xsd">
  <request>
    <requestType>Project Issue</requestType>
    <identifier>3</identifier>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Admin User (DEV)</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.DESCRIPTION</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Test - Pls Ignore</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.KNTA_ESCALATION_LEVEL</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Project</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.KNTA_MASTER_PROJ_REF</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>P0912002 IPTV Residential Phase 1</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.PRIORITY_CODE</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Normal</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
    <common:simpleField>
      <common:token>REQ.WORKFLOW_ID</common:token>
      <common:stringValue>Issue Management Process</common:stringValue>
    </common:simpleField>
  </request>

</di:itg_dataImport>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<requests xmlns:di="http://www.mercury.com/itg/data_import/1.0" xmlns:x="http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types" xmlns:common="http://www.mercury.com/itg/common/2.0/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <request>
        <requestType>
            <requestType xmlns="http://www.mercury.com/itg/dm/2.0/types">Project Issue</requestType></requestType>
    </request>
</requests>
```

**A rule to remember**: XPath treats unprefixed names as belonging to "no namespace". In order to deal with this, define this namespace in your XSLT code, but with a prefix -- then prefix the names with this prefix.